# How does random map generation work

Tags: java, random

I am currently working on a text based zombie RPG simulator where there will be a randomly generated city to explore and do things in. I was originally planning to save the city in a 2D array, but then I realized that if I would do that, my array would take up gigabytes of data for just number storage. After doing some research I discovered something called perlin noise, which is an algorithm that generates virtually infinite and random looking terrain based on a single seed, and I'm curious if I could do something similar with my city. Any ideas guys?

---

I realize I didn't leave you guys with much information about what I need.
The city I want generated should be represented by a grid of coordinates, where each coordinate plots a separate
 building on the map. Buildings however should be arranged in a specific way. If it is a financial district, then office buildings and  should spawn more frequently. If it is a residential district then buildings like apartment buildings and laundromats should be generated more frequently. If it is a park, then no buildings should be generated.

Also, some buildings should take up more coordinates than others, such as malls and such.

Highways across the city should also be generated, but this is not important if it complicates the code too much, as this is meant to be a simple learning project.

Comment: How do you define your city? What are the elements you want to store? What is the structure? One needs more information to tackle such problems...

Comment: yea haha I noticed that after I asked the question

Comment: I made an attempt to answer the question, but you have to realize that there is no "real" answer to such questions.

Comment: "my array would take up gigabytes of data for just number storage" that's a lot of exaggeration.

Comment: well, the plan eventually is to generate more than just one city. Maybe even a world but that's getting a little too ambitious, seeing as how it would take months for the player to explore the entirety of a single city. Also you need to remember that map generation wont stop with the buildings. The buildings themselves will be data structures that hold objects just as the city holds buildings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perlin noise mainly works by combining several "images" (see for instance here: http://devmag.org.za/2009/04/25/perlin-noise/) where some have lower frequencies and other higher. So what you could do is use the value at a certain coordinate of the lower frequencies to determine the type of area in your city. Say for instance the pixel of the image at the lowest frequency is less than 0.5 and that of the second lowest as well, you could state that you are in a financial part of your city. Then the higher frequencies (who vary more) determine the type of building or object (tree,...).

However you will have to experiment with parameters to make it quite realistic.

I know this is kind of a basic answer, but feel free to comment on this procedure.

Roads can probably not be generated using Perlin noise itself, but for instance by an algorithm that does some postprocessing (say for instance you are are in a financial district, you could program a rule that if there is a building on the left of a certain tile and on the right and there is no building at the tile itself, you should introduce a road.

Comment: This is actually very helpful, thanks dude. I'll definitely look into it some more.

Comment: This stuff is pretty cool! I'm actually getting it to work

Comment: Is it possible to see some results? I'm quite curious... :D. If you can't reveal the project, no problem :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use random points and a relaxation like in this tutorial: http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/game-programming/polygon-map-generation/. It also uses a delaunay triangulation and the dual voronoi-diagram and noisy edges.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the game is a grid-based text-based game, of course you can use the provided method and look at the color of the cell. On the other hand is determining which cell of the Delaunay-triangulation should be used quite expensive (especially when using a large anount of dots).

Comment: This is some pretty cool stuff. It's a bit too complicated for me at this stage in my programming career haha. Thank you though, I will definitely read into it.